# Other way to store data than arrays for face encodings

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning, face-recognition

I'm working a face recognition system where you input the folder of known faces, and it finds pictures of them in another folder. I'm using the face_recognition as fr, library, os, and copy from shutil as c. Here's the code.

```
if results[0] == True:
    c(file_name, "/home/deeplearning/Pictures" + end_name)
```

I get the error : `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`

How can I store them so the truth value is different for each encoding?

Comment: That error has nothing to do with how you are storing the image in an array, it's how you are trying to apply some logical test

Comment: Presumably you get a 2D matrix in your code. `if results[0] == True:` would then be equivalent to something like `if [0, 0, False, 0] == True`. In that case, the array _as a whole_ is truthy, but the only actual `bool` in the list is `False`. You might get away with truthy-ness in Python, but `numpy` is asking you to be specific about what it's supposed to be comparing since it uses array programming.

Comment: @roganjosh ok, that makes sense, but what can i do to fix it?

Comment: Please reduce the problem down to a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The steps that get you to the point at which you're having issues are irrelevant, you just need to give a _representative_ example of what your data is before the `if` check and what you expect to come out of that.

Comment: @roganjosh done, i think

Comment: It isn't because we can't see the data

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I changed `if results[0] == True:` to `if results[0] is True`.

As @roganjosh pointed out, it was a logic error. Sorry for the stupid question.